# Loop selection not including one edge

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I'm trying to select edges with loop selection, But there is part of edges isolated which seemed to be made when I bevelled.
But I want to them to be loop in order to bevel more.
There is no separated vertices so I cannot merge them by using Remove doubles.
How can I connect those three edges together?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that those edges establish an edge loop. Once the edgeflow reaches the corner, it has two possible ways, each one with the same weight. So it's expected, in my opinion, that the selection stops there and wait for user's decision.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! now I understood better what is loop, right, it works only when the direction is clear. But I wanted loop because I wanted to bevel, otherwise part of the bevel gets mess though I did by hand eventually :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The question you'd need to ask yourself is:

> "How does Blender know where a loop is running along anyways?"

Basically, a loop can only be found if there is four edges connecting to a point. See this GIF for illustration:

[image: edge loop]

I'm selecting the two edges first which are the loop that I intend to select, then the two perpendicular edges that branch off from them. Loop selection takes a single edge as an input (the one you click on), and follows the path along this direction UNTIL there is a case where a different amount than four edges are forming a vertex point. Along this path, the edge that is "in the middle" will be the one considered to form the loop. As your beveled edge gives you a corner case where only three edges meet, loop selection stops there. How would Blender know if you want to go left or right?

To do the selection you want, try either Shortest Path select by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> clicking, like this:

[image: Ctrl Click]

or select the faces which are inside the desired loop, and use the boundary select tool from the menu like this:

[image: Boundary Select]

Comment: Oh I see so the loop needs 4 edges! Thank you for great explanation :) So I cannot make bevel with current model unless I add more vertices... I kind of did without bevel function. It is difficult to make a clean model..!

Comment: @haruka.k oh yes, you CAN bevel. Blender supports n-gons on one hand, and has a very clever bevel algorithm on the other hand. Just try it  :)